# How to create view for my two tables in HANA

Tags: hana

I have two tables in HANA, that is, A and B.

Data are inserted into A in batch mode, and B is used is to log the current batch that is ready to be used in A(When insert into A is done, will log its batch in B).

Sample data are:

```
A

name score batch_id
Tom  80    1
Jack 30    1
Alex 90    1

Tom  90    2
Jack 50    2
Alex 70    2


Tom  70    3
Jack 60    3
Alex 80    3

B
table_name    batch_id
A     1
A     2
A     3
```

I have the following sql to get the latest batch from A that is ready be used:

```
select * from A where a.batch_id = (select max(batch_id) from B where table_name = 'A')
```

I want to model the above sql with attribute view, analytic view or compute view, but there are no measures defined in the sql, it looks that it can't be created as analytic view or compute view.

I would ask what type of view I should created, and how to model it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use rank node to data source of table B, partition by column Table_Name, Descending  Order , threshold value 1, this will automatically give you max value ;  put filter on Data source Node on column Table_name as A,

Then use the output of Rank node to Join with data source of Table A,

You should use CALC View with at least one Key Figure;

Alternatively you can use Table Function to write Sql Cod ein it but bottom line is you should have key Figure